# Latexmk and missing pdflatex command

Tags: latexmk

Following the guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738755/dont-make-me-manually-abort-a-latex-compile-when-theres-an-error) and the details provided on the latexmk installation note, I managed to set up a latexmk executable in my bin. Now hopefully this should've meant I was done and ready to compile all my latex and get beautiful little pdfs out of it.

Sadly when I ran:

```
latexmk -pvc -pdflatex foo.tex
```

I only got this in response:

```
sh: pdflatex: command not found
```

Any ideas of what might have gone wrong? Maybe a line of the latexmk file that I need to have a look at?

EDIT: This is on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6, and I have MacTex installed through homebrew. I have not used any of the things provided by MacTex though as I prefer writing in sublime text.

EDIT 2: I clearly had a brain-fart moment as I didn't follow the guide as I said and wrote something wrong. Thanks Collins for spotting it.

Comment: Erh, perhaps you should start over. (1) which operating system are you using? (2) Which LaTeX installation are you using? For (2) I generally use TeXLive which provides `latexmk` out of the box. From the error message, you either have no LaTeX installed (latexmk does not provide any latex it just calls it) or two, your paths aren't setup correctly.

Comment: I would probably recommend using the proper mactex and not homebrew as many osers have had issues with it. Proper mactex automatically adds itself to the path and already include latexmk. The proper mactex is also the easiest latex to install by far.

Comment: Since you installed MacTeX which installs a full TeX Live you already have latexmk installed. Does Sublime Text ‘know’ where the TeX binaries are located? Does it find pdflatex without trying to use latexmk?

Comment: Sublime is only used to write the latex file. I use latexmk through my terminal.

Comment: A "proper" installation of mactex also did not help. It's just as bad, bar the fact that it's even worse, it's harder to uninstall now that it's no longer covered by the brew. It is easy to find the Tex bin folder, but it isn't linked to the path automatically- and I've already messed around too much with my Path to be confident in pulling off anything with it.

Comment: What is $PATH in Terminal? Are you changing it?

Comment: Your command line should be `latexmk -pvc -pdf foo.tex`, rather than the one you wrote.  Latexmk should have given a fatal error about a bad option. See the latexmk documentation for information about the correct form of the -pdflatex option, which is used to redefine the command that latexmk uses to set the command used to invoke pdflatex.